# Text visualizer is not available in VS2012 debugger

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2012, debuggervisualizer

I want to see this lambda expression in the Text Visualizer:

```
Func<int, int, int> v = (int x, int y) => x + y;
```

However, when I stop debugger after this line, `v` variable in the Watch window doesn't contain magnify glass icon, which is supposed to open the list of available visualizers. For example, as shown here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/saraford/archive/2008/09/23/did-you-know-how-to-use-the-text-visualizer-319.aspx?Redirected=true

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that text visualizer is available for expression:

```
Expression<Func<int, int, int>> v = (int x, int y) => x + y;
```

Answer (score 0):

Text visualizer is not applicable to `Func` values because they are not text.